# Canadian visiting family in US while applying for jobs in order to get an interview

Tags: visas, usa, canada, h1b-visas, working-visas

I am a Canadian citizen who is going to be visiting extended family in the US. However, on the side, I might also be applying for jobs so that I can at least get an interview.

I am highly aware that Canadian Citizen would need a TN or H1-B visas to work in the US.

However, is it ok for me to just enter the US with my Canadian passport as a visitor in order to intentionally visit extended family while, on the side, apply for jobs in order to get an interview?  ( Moreover, once the prospective employer who interviews me wants to hire me,  I can just go back up to the US-Canadian border in order to get my TN or H1-B visa with all the proper supporting documentation )

Does the aforementioned scenario sound legal?